# Linking to Blueprint CSS tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tabs, blueprint-css

I'm using Blueprint CSS as the framework for a website I'm currently building, I'm also using the tabs plugin (http://blueprintcss.org/demos/tabs.html) which works really nicely, however I'd like to be able to directly link to a tab (from the address bar) this doesn't seem to be possible as a standard feature so I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me out here?

Comment: yes but not on their website. :P They have some kind of url mask.  Basically you would want to remove the "return false;" in the click event, and then switch tabs on page load based on example.com/test.html#text2 (text2 being the second tab)

Comment: thanks for the reply, I just gave this a go but it didn't seem to work

Comment: actually, this isn't entirely true. I just noticed that the URL is now updating when I click on a tab however I cannot directly navigate to a tab with just a URL (possibly something to do with WordPress)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does too work.

http://pastebin.com/bQun2DNV

has to be tested as an html file.

key code snippet:

```
$("ul.tabs a[href="+location.hash+"]").click();
```